# How should one best recode this example extension method to be generic for all numeric types?

Tags: c#-4.0

How should one best recode this example extension method to be generic for all numeric types?

```
public static float clip(this float v, float lo, float hi)
{ return Math.Max(lo, Math.Min(hi, v)); }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// IComparable constraint for numeric types like int and float that implement IComparable
public static T clip<T>(this T v, T lo, T hi) where T : IComparable<T>
{
  // Since T implements IComparable, we can use CompareTo
  if(v.CompareTo(lo)<0)
    v=lo; // make sure v is not too low
  if(v.CompareTo(hi)>0)
    v=hi; // make sure v is not too high
  return v;
}
```

Comment: You threw in string for free :) Thanks Peter. Now I'll post a separate question to find out why my own attempt was rejceted by the compiler.

Comment: Note that this will introduce boxing.